# Show $P = Q(Q^TQ)^{-1}Q^T$ is a projector? and what is the subspace

Tags: matrices

Let Q be a n×p matrix with n≥p of rank p.

Show $$P = Q(Q^TQ)^{-1}Q^T$$ is a projector. And what is the subspace L of R^n onto which does P project?
I was thinking $$P=QQ^T$$ is a projector, but how about the other stuff?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Since the last matrix is $Q$ in the product expression for $P$, it follows that the column space of $P$ is at most the column space of $Q$. It remains to compute the null space.

Answer (score 0):

$P$ projects vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to the range of $Q$, namely, for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $Px \in {\rm range}(Q)$. For vectors already in the range, we have $PQx = Qx$.